# Church–Turing Thesis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, computational-physics, quantum-computer

Can the [Church–Turing Thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) be proved assuming classical mechanics, how is the proof or disproof?

Edited: I was looking for a proof of "everything computable by a device obeying CM is computable by a Turing machine", but it seems obvious now.

My followup question is why does it hold for QM?

Comment: What does Church–Turing have to do with classical mechanics? The article you linked to provides the answer: "Despite the fact that it cannot be formally proven […]"

Comment: @Will: there is also physical CTT and quantum CTT (again in the linked-in article). Can't that be somehow relevant (I have no clue though)?

Comment: What do you mean by classical mechanics? Unlike the Standard Model, say, it's not a single actual well-defined theory of physics, and if you're not careful about your assumptions, then you get uncomputable behavior. For example, Newtonian gravity with point masses is problematic, as is the wave equation with computable initial data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked and [**answered on mathoverflow**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54820/physics-and-churchturing-thesis). You should read it there. We could have migrated it but that site is independent of SE network.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose it follows directly since turing machines can simulate CM? And same with QM it seems.

Answer (score -1):

> everything computable by a device obeying CM is computable by a Turing machine

This could be proved by a toy classical mechanics model.

Let's begin by simple task. Say we want to design simple mechanical machine which would implement [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) function on a tiny subset of natural numbers $(0,1)$. So we need to implement bitwise AND truth table:
$$ \begin{align}
     0~0 \to 0\\  
     0~1 \to 0\\
     1~0 \to 0\\
     1~1 \to 1 
\end{align} 
$$

Idea for a two bits addition goes like this. We build a tube of height $h$ which has some valve at the bottom. Input bit is represented by putting automatically a small ball of diameter $D$ into the tube and letting it fall freely down to the valve. Valve is constructed so, that in opens just in case a pair of balls weights acts on it, then it opens letting these balls through which we will denote as output $1$ signal. No balls out - $0$ signal.

Then maximum time needed for addition operation to work out is:
$$ t_{max} = \sqrt {\frac {2h}{g}} + \sqrt {\frac {2(h-D)}{g}}+\tau \tag 1 $$

where $\tau$ is time buffer for everything else - pause between separate ball inputs, time needed for valve to open, various response times, etc.

We can easily see that having finite tube height $h$ bitwise AND operation on our two "bits" is performed in a finite time and considering that valve is designed in a good way,- it should produce correct answer. If these prerequisites are met, we can call our bit adding device [an effective method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_method), as this is required by Church–Turing thesis for computable functions.

**Proof by negation**

Now, we want to extend our bitwise AND machine to operate on whole natural numbers $N_1,N_2$. Skipping natural number conversion part to bit-stream for simplicity, let's just say that natural number is represented by a $k$ series of bits, so that if we would like to perform our bitwise AND operation on our two natural numbers (on they each bit separately), so we have to have $k$ tubes OR we would need to use same tube in a row of operations which would take total time of :

$$ t_{max} = k \left( \sqrt {\frac {2h}{g}} + \sqrt {\frac {2(h-D)}{g}}+\tau \right) \tag 2 $$

For AND'ing *arbitrary* pair of natural numbers, we should see that $k \to \infty$, because natural number set is infinite and so is infinite number of bits (tubes/operations) needed to represent arbitrary long natural number addition. So as $k \to \infty$, $t_{max} \to \infty$ too.

This proves that we can't build our machine to effectively bitwise add any pair of natural numbers, and so we can't build *any* Turing machine which would implement the same algorithm effectively.

Comment: Reasons for a downvote? Somebody don't like the reality that no computable function operating on whole natural numbers set exist, apart in **small** natural number sub-set allowed by computing resources ?

Comment: Your answer has several serious issues. Maybe most importantly, you don't seem to know the concept of a Turing machine. To perform, say, an OR operation on k bits, a Turing machine would also need a time which would grow at least linearly with k (just as any other operation acting on k bits).

Comment: Yes, I know that. My point was addressing OP quote, i. e. everything what we can or can't do with my mechanical computer instance, - applies generally to any Turing machine instance. So you miss my point completely. Another conclusion is that due to limited resources no computable function exist which would operate on whole natural number set as this would involve halting problem.

Comment: If you know that, then why do you claim the contrary in your answer? Your answer also claims that an example where something does not work provides a proof that something doesn't work, it does not address the question whether *"everything computable by a device obeying CM is computable by a Turing machine"* (rather, you try to demonstrate the opposite: that some things computable by TMs are not computable by CM), and it does not really address the Church-Turing-thesis. -- Also, note that you are answering a 12-year old question, so likely the OP won't wonder about it any more.

Comment: It addresses that too, as 1 tube operation is fully computable, so does 2 bits operation must be computable on Turing machine. And yes I believe that my CM example is specific instance of Turing machine so it must apply to them all. Sure it's not a proof in a strict sense, but rather a hypothesis. And I don't care about 12 years as long as I'm or others are interested in this issue.